# Comparing text files using Bash and AWK

Tags: scripting, awk, diff

I have two text files, and I want to compare their corresponding values according to their rows and columns. By comparing, I mean to check if the values are equal and echo if the values are the same or not. Here are the files:

`file1.txt`

```
Name  Col1  Col2  Col3  
-----------------------
row1  1     4     7        
row2  2     5     8         
row3  3     6     9
```

`file2.txt`

```
Name  Col1  Col2  Col3  
-----------------------
row2  1     4     11        
row1  2     5     12
```

Here are the constraints:

- compare only the rows that exist (that is, since row3 exists in file1.txt, but not in file2.txt, no comparison is needed)
- Must use [AWK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK)
- The rows may be out of order in the files
- No double arrays since my version of AWK doesn't support it

I am thinking of something like this:

```
awk 'NR>2 {next}
{
    for (i=2;i<NR;i++)              #For each row of file1.txt
    {     
        for(j=1;i<NF;j++)           #For each column of file1.txt
        {
             // Check if row and column of file1.txt is equal to row and column of file2.txt.
        } 
    }
}
' file1.txt file2.txt
```

How do you compare values of two different text files? Let me know if more explanation is needed.

All I'm asking for is a general structure using AWK. Hopefully I can figure out the rest.

Comment: That's the kind of job I'd use `diff(1)` for, perhaps with a little post-massage by `grep(1)` to get rid of missing rows, and possibly preprocessing with `sort(1)` for out-of-order lines...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to do it, here's a solution with `gawk 4.x`:

```
$ awk '
    FNR < 2 { next }
    FNR == NR {
        for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) {
            a[$1][i] = $i;
        }
        next;
    }
    ($1 in a) {
      for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) {
          if (a[$1][i] == $i) {
              printf("%s->Col%d: Equal\n", $1, i-1);
          } else {
              printf("%s->Col%d: Not Equal\n", $1, i-1);
          }
       }
  }
' file1.txt file2.txt
row2->Col1: Not Equal
row2->Col2: Not Equal
row2->Col3: Not Equal
row1->Col1: Not Equal
row1->Col2: Not Equal
row1->Col3: Not Equal
```

**Explanation**

- `FNR < 2 { next }`: skip first two lines
- `FNR == NR`: only true when we processing first file. We save each column value in associative array `a`, with form `a[ROW][COLUMN]`.
- `($1 in a)`: check if row in file2 existed in file1. If true, we loop through all its column value, compare with value in file1.

With older `gawk` version, you can try:

```
$ awk '
    FNR < 2 { next }
    FNR == NR {
        for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) {
            a[i,$1] = $i;
            b[$1];
        }
        next;
    }
    ($1 in b) {
      for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) {
          if (a[i,$1] == $i) {
              printf("%s->Col%d: Equal\n", $1, i-1);
          } else {
              printf("%s->Col%d: Not Equal\n", $1, i-1);
          }
       }
  }
' file1.txt file2.txt
```

Comment: I keep getting syntax errors when putting values into the associative array

Comment: Still getting the same error. Not sure why but it keeps saying syntax error

Comment: Do you an idea as to why?

Comment: What is your `awk` version?

Comment: I have GNU Awk 3.1.6

Comment: Is it possible that this version of `awk` doesn't support double arrays?

Comment: @Nosscire: `gawk` version >= 4.0 has array of arrays, 3.x doesn't.

Comment: Do you have a solution that doesn't use double arrays?

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 4):

This one outputs the lines from file2 where the name is in both files but any of the values differ

```
awk 'NR==FNR {f1[$1]=$0; next} $1 in f1 && $0 != f1[$1]' file1.txt file2.txt
```

```
row2  1     4     11        
row1  2     5     12
```

I realized that even a difference in whitespace will give false results. We can "normalize" the lines:

```
awk '
    NR==FNR  {$1=$1; f1[$1]=$0; next} 
    $1 in f1 {$1=$1; if ($0 != f1[$1]) print}
' file1.txt file2.txt
```

```
row2 1 4 11
row1 2 5 12
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out inside for inner for loop:

```
awk ' {
      if(i == j)
           print "Same value";
      else
           print "Not the same";
       }'
```

This is a simple conditional statement that might help, but it may need some additional tweaking with comparing two different text files...