# I am having some technical issue with awk code

Tags: awk

This is related to one of my previous question: [Comparing text files using Bash and AWK](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138054/comparing-text-files-using-bash-and-awk/)

file1.txt

```
Name  Col1  Col2  Col3  
-----------------------
row1  1     4     7        
row2  2     5     8         
row3  3     6     9
```

file2.txt

```
Name  Col1  Col2  Col3  
-----------------------        
row1  1     4     7
row2  2     5     999
```

I have somewhat figured out a way to compare two files. But for some reason it is not giving me the result that I want. Here is the code I use to compare the files.

```
awk '
FNR < 2 { next }
FNR == NR {
    for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) 
    {
        a[i,$1] = $i; 
    }    
    b[$1];
    next;

}
($1 in b) {
   for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) 
   {
      if (a[i,$1] == $i) 
          printf("%s->Col%d: %d vs %d: Equal\n", $1, i-1, a[i,$1], $i);
      else 
          printf("%s->Col%d: %d vs %d: Not Equal\n", $1, i-1, a[i,$1], $i);
   }
} ' file1.txt file2.txt
```

Expected result:

```
row2->Col1: 1 vs 1: Equal
row2->Col2: 4 vs 4: Equal
row2->Col3: 7 vs 7: Equal
row1->Col1: 2 vs 2: Equal
row1->Col2: 5 vs 5: Equal
row1->Col3: 8 vs 999: Not Equal
```

Actual result:

```
row2->Col1: 1 vs 1: Equal
row2->Col2: 4 vs 4: Equal
row2->Col3: 0 vs 7: Not Equal
row1->Col1: 2 vs 2: Equal
row1->Col2: 5 vs 5: Equal
row1->Col3: 0 vs 999: Not Equal
```

I don't know why 0 is part of the output. Does anyone know why 0 is there?

EDIT: Here is the problem. The first for loop only iterates once. Why?

Comment: The b array contains only 0. I'm not very good with awk, what does ($1 in b) do? Goes through all b array elements?

Comment: @polym Yes exactly

Comment: did you forget to assign any values to these array elements? you only created them in line 6 of your awk expression `b[$1];`, which results in 0s

Comment: @polym I created the `b[$1];` array because I need it as reference for comparing the second file. Check the actual output (lines 1 and 4). There is an actual comparison going on there so assigning a value to `b[$1]` is not the issue. See the EDIT in my answer. The problem is something with the first for loop

Comment: Please stop [crossposting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24316140/unexpected-result-comparing-values-of-rows-and-columns-in-two-text-files).

Answer (score 2):

Bug: change

```
FNR == NR {
    for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) 
    {
        a[i,$1] = $i; 
        b[$1];
        next;
    }
}
```

to

```
FNR == NR {
    for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) 
    {
        a[i,$1] = $i; 
    }
    b[$1];
    next;
}
```

You were calling `next` after `i==2`

Comment: @glenn_jackman Thanks! But that only solved part of the problem. Now the output looks my this (see edit in the question)

Comment: @Nosscire: My mistypo in original question. After glenn jackman fixed, it now works.

Comment: @Gnouc I updated the question with the error I am still getting. Check lines 3 and 6 of the Actual Output in the question. Still have no idea as to why it is not happening

Comment: It works perfect for me. You can add a `print` after every `a[i,$1] = $i`.